# javafx - How to get a cell value of selected row

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to solve a basic problem. Could you please have a look at this code and push me forward a little bit?

I have this

```
public class StrediskoController {
private Stage dialogStage;

@FXML private TableView strediskaTableView = new TableView<>();
@FXML private Label nameLabel;

private ObservableList<Stredisko> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML public void initialize() {
    System.out.println("test");
    strediskaTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
        if (strediskaTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {

            nameLabel.setText(".....");

        }
    });

}

public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage) { this.dialogStage = dialogStage; }

public void GetStrediska() {
    new StrediskoDAO().SeeAllStredisko(data, strediskaTableView);
}
```

I want to select a row in tableview and put a value of second column into label.

My StrediskoDAO looks like:

```
public void SeeAllStredisko(ObservableList data, TableView<Stredisko> stredisko)
{
    try
    {
        String select = "Select * from stredisko";
        PreparedStatement stmt = DatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(select);
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery();

        for(int i=0 ; i<rst.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rst.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            stredisko.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        while(rst.next())
        {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int i = 1; i <= rst.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                row.add(rst.getString(i));
                System.out.println(row);
            }

            data.add(row);
        }
        stredisko.setItems(data);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and Stredisko

```
public class Stredisko {
private SimpleIntegerProperty stredisko_Id;
private SimpleStringProperty name;


public Stredisko(int stredisko_Id, String name) {
    this.stredisko_Id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(stredisko_Id);
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}



public int getStredisko_Id() {
    return stredisko_Id.get();
}

public SimpleIntegerProperty stredisko_IdProperty() {
    return stredisko_Id;
}

public void setStredisko_Id(int stredisko_Id) {
    this.stredisko_Id.set(stredisko_Id);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
```

I am just a beginner in JavaFX and I would be really happy if you help me :-)

Thank you guys.

Comment: @James_D there is "name"

Comment: OK, I'm confused by your code. In the `SeeAllStredisko` method you don't create any `Stredisko` objects. You just populate the table with a list of lists of strings. You need to decide if you are using a model class (i.e. `Stredisko`), which is the preferred approach, or if you are just going to create this completely generically with a list of lists. Choose which approach and use it. Don't use raw types, i.e. you should never have `TableView` but always `TableView<Strdisko>` (in the first approach) or `TableView<List<String>>` (in the second). You need to fix this before you can continue.

Comment: Similarly, you should always have `ObservableList<...>` and *never* `ObservableList`.

Comment: @James_D I think I understand, thank you very much